# pythonのmatplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, csv

一番下に載せたカンマ区切りのcsvファイルを、contourで等高線にしたいです。
空白欄のNANの部分を0に置き換えた上で下記のコードで実行すると、等高線は出てくるのですが、0という値は考えないので本当は出てきてほしくないです。

・NANの空欄ところの処理はどうすれば良いのでしょうか？
・y軸の値は0.01〜1.00なのに、実行すると0~100になってしまうのはなぜでしょうか？
・colorbarを0~1で作成したいのに0~1.05で作成されてしまうのはなぜでしょうか？

お願いいたします。

```
import pandas as pd
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('xyz.csv')

Xgrid = data.columns.values.astype(np.float32)
Ygrid = data.index.values.astype(np.float32)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(Xgrid, Ygrid)
Z = data.as_matrix()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax.set_title("contour")
contour = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z)
print(type(contour))
fig.colorbar(contour)
contour.set_clim(vmin=0, vmax=1)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')

plt.show()
```

[image]

↓csv

```
NAN,2,4,6,8,10,12
0.01,0.010498504,0.011303108,0.011666359,0.012759248,0.013354973,0.01397708
0.02,0.020531799,0.021815456,0.024085167,0.025540175,0.026609816,0.028023467
0.03,0.031287853,0.032856921,0.036288045,0.038293067,0.040738222,0.042261579
0.04,0.040915843,0.044471039,0.047144054,0.051531803,0.05450982,0.056534606
0.05,0.051976115,0.055683682,0.058482424,0.06367321,0.067322789,0.071311501
0.06,0.061870274,0.067445033,0.071195003,0.075676264,0.08072713,0.086071679
0.07,0.072325854,0.077800658,0.083336758,0.088376392,0.093933563,0.09905182
0.08,0.082514305,0.088789185,0.094961063,0.101997795,0.107325018,0.114141031
0.09,0.092328013,0.100336957,0.106766471,0.11260026,0.120538155,0.127562176
0.1,0.102940751,0.11001562,0.117793483,0.125119284,0.133941713,0.141182709
0.11,0.114300193,0.121964344,0.130636839,0.138746522,0.146051339,0.155901877
0.12,0.12402152,0.131957239,0.141518621,0.150602168,0.159316979,0.168641447
0.13,0.134382281,0.143599567,0.152837923,0.162689941,0.172675174,0.182777689
0.14,0.143943924,0.155212901,0.165663865,0.175482449,0.186231189,0.196459954
0.15,0.154608556,0.164867969,0.175699947,0.187199308,0.198227365,0.210015533
0.16,0.163087497,0.175821756,0.188129377,0.200734339,0.212353855,0.223795837
0.17,0.173300677,0.186919555,0.198873068,0.21091243,0.224448332,0.236318693
0.18,0.183370367,0.196336055,0.210299291,0.222044012,0.236659655,0.250034392
0.19,0.192693267,0.205354039,0.219712742,0.233238718,0.247452278,0.261774324
0.2,0.201063546,0.213856315,0.228936993,0.243842837,0.256504132,0.27029175
0.21,0.207033598,0.220144082,0.235889182,0.250454848,0.264349735,0.278523329
0.22,0.212145499,0.224960035,0.240851238,0.256447538,0.270797621,0.284433216
0.23,0.215390992,0.22805664,0.244042399,0.260095636,0.274851199,0.289883206
0.24,0.21652219,0.230321215,0.246199705,0.262167266,0.278122464,0.293163265
0.25,0.218042413,0.231010539,0.247740563,0.264053875,0.279665063,0.295342337
0.26,0.218706313,0.232268858,0.24911033,0.265084335,0.281139575,0.296936656
0.27,0.21882255,0.232237426,0.249708493,0.265538486,0.28179738,0.298049396
0.28,0.219465989,0.232414699,0.249582244,0.26639507,0.282879908,0.299286035
0.29,0.219508566,0.232876077,0.250183802,0.266904423,0.283018695,0.299746804
0.3,0.219929544,0.23339849,0.249936701,0.266965806,0.283753208,0.299838313
0.31,0.219816528,0.233078947,0.250194686,0.26719236,0.284023731,0.299815066
0.32,0.219617402,0.232591013,0.25038528,0.267403763,0.283744415,0.300448144
0.33,0.220095149,0.232191193,0.250672346,0.267757001,0.283978804,0.30072154
0.34,0.220351828,0.232884958,0.250482536,0.26713411,0.284114022,0.300865639
0.35,0.219390413,0.233235062,0.250437173,0.267477597,0.284237137,0.300712659
0.36,0.219292635,0.233026183,0.250305351,0.26751286,0.284197956,0.300855016
0.37,0.220072598,0.232782739,0.250625503,0.267692309,0.284273706,0.301246217
0.38,0.220187442,0.233164623,0.250407047,0.268110153,0.284477796,0.300542352
0.39,0.219831069,0.233023484,0.250275573,0.267880291,0.284521853,0.300700208
0.4,0.220497755,0.233063362,0.250792588,0.267558223,0.284131697,0.30124465
0.41,0.219847351,0.2323312,0.250586844,0.267560051,0.284299914,0.300857803
0.42,0.219608695,0.233387258,0.250122332,0.267461402,0.284188553,0.300916226
0.43,0.220053443,0.233357655,0.250695767,0.267699884,0.284379408,0.301623399
0.44,0.219707866,0.232953742,0.250175096,0.268018121,0.284718193,0.301034988
0.45,0.219991276,0.232894535,0.250285847,0.267787127,0.284882056,0.301085052
0.46,0.220442205,0.232965758,0.250698031,0.267412208,0.285239997,0.300878612
0.47,0.220056839,0.232871723,0.24984049,0.268041107,0.284371049,0.300906126
0.48,0.220258925,0.232792055,0.250162993,0.267353263,0.284232349,0.302089392
0.49,0.220103333,0.232835503,0.250367431,0.267592702,0.284598647,0.300939909
0.5,0.219739995,0.233169325,0.250510659,0.267820736,0.284283806,0.300991366
0.51,0.220196497,0.232750523,0.250268869,0.267672109,0.2844744,0.301215656
0.52,0.219941385,0.232702461,0.250450059,0.267648339,0.284707483,0.301218529
0.53,0.219920924,0.232836286,0.250763681,0.267728965,0.284330301,0.301033769
0.54,0.2195925,0.233089569,0.250185457,0.267835189,0.284663514,0.301161934
0.55,0.22022671,0.23290211,0.250306831,0.267736801,0.284719934,0.300941215
0.56,0.219946958,0.233725259,0.250644658,0.267221789,0.284268308,0.301034727
0.57,0.219668773,0.232691404,0.250536257,0.267436849,0.284598734,0.300946526
0.58,0.219732159,0.233143204,0.250283757,0.268280459,0.284561382,0.301401983
0.59,0.220201199,0.233082169,0.250300562,0.26742048,0.284205096,0.301129022
0.6,0.219867377,0.232808076,0.250362381,0.267516169,0.284812053,0.301209474
0.61,0.220375511,0.232911775,0.25045241,0.267654869,0.284370962,0.301204511
0.62,0.220005642,0.232778124,0.250273222,0.267715469,0.285006043,0.301253357
0.63,0.220552348,0.23297281,0.25038972,0.267732012,0.284603784,0.301036642
0.64,0.219890276,0.232946167,0.25054627,0.268034925,0.284595687,0.300856584
0.65,0.219795719,0.23260921,0.250004092,0.267503021,0.284633736,0.301082353
0.66,0.219688624,0.233257351,0.250739998,0.267005161,0.284193255,0.301476253
0.67,0.2201581,0.232875815,0.250249365,0.267744463,0.28441737,0.301464847
0.68,0.219671211,0.233063362,0.250348101,0.267645727,0.284723417,0.300871821
0.69,0.219572736,0.232403031,0.250347753,0.267153701,0.284043409,0.301305075
0.7,0.219641346,0.233100801,0.250127382,0.267511902,0.284367131,0.30090482
0.71,0.219866506,0.232374386,0.250328337,0.267767711,0.284516454,0.301294801
0.72,0.219925626,0.23306014,0.250311184,0.267803148,0.284384545,0.300918141
0.73,0.219401297,0.232465808,0.250144273,0.267540983,0.284384371,0.301489749
0.74,0.219384493,0.232605815,0.250414448,0.267569542,0.284585065,0.301088622
0.75,0.219415315,0.233137632,0.25030152,0.267807849,0.284549018,0.301398849
0.76,0.219612178,0.233105851,0.250490111,0.267305288,0.284442359,0.301057016
0.77,0.219539736,0.23256794,0.250081148,0.267713293,0.284764078,0.301101595
0.78,0.219816441,0.232915432,0.250096821,0.267713728,0.284453329,0.301333808
0.79,0.219972469,0.232768982,0.24998781,0.267585127,0.284702869,0.30101592
0.8,0.219887838,0.232618614,0.250205831,0.267592441,0.284430953,0.301223318
0.81,0.219642913,0.232876512,0.250270871,0.268097005,0.284503829,0.301123363
0.82,0.22020355,0.232187188,0.250665293,0.267765012,0.284325599,0.301280696
0.83,0.219960976,0.232796147,0.250197298,0.26766793,0.284211452,0.300970383
0.84,0.220294798,0.233341024,0.249983979,0.267661748,0.28498741,0.301062327
0.85,0.220203201,0.232638117,0.250231516,0.267706762,0.284585239,0.301012785
0.86,0.219732681,0.233002152,0.249933044,0.268137057,0.284056469,0.301411387
0.87,0.220309774,0.232700197,0.250412271,0.267040686,0.284316805,0.301126932
0.88,0.21992223,0.23298587,0.25059233,0.267595227,0.284709834,0.301331022
0.89,0.219937293,0.232421925,0.250457025,0.26749771,0.284546928,0.301592577
0.9,0.219867551,0.232840814,0.250393203,0.267710245,0.284432259,0.30119206
0.91,0.220106381,0.232745299,0.250619234,0.26768308,0.284381149,0.301313869
0.92,0.21973599,0.232533112,0.250139484,0.267840065,0.284253332,0.301413999
0.93,0.220214085,0.2332954,0.250247189,0.26817676,0.284530472,0.301107777
0.94,0.220175949,0.233417384,0.250984575,0.267739936,0.283874147,0.301251354
0.95,0.219914046,0.233293224,0.250134434,0.267305897,0.284527686,0.301546256
0.96,0.220257271,0.233454736,0.249868091,0.267342553,0.284554503,0.300924933
0.97,0.220140338,0.233138938,0.250467734,0.267070289,0.284317589,0.301023233
0.98,0.220079128,0.233214078,0.250423242,0.267028931,0.284501478,0.301416872
0.99,0.220183437,0.233474936,0.250254415,0.267778855,0.284733952,0.301398936
1,0.219799463,0.232916651,0.25021654,0.267589045,0.284452023,0.300886797
```

Comment: `read_csv()` で index に使うカラムを指定するのはどうでしょうか。 `data = pd.read_csv('xyz.csv', index_col=0)`

Comment: csvの各行・各列のデータは何を表していて、それはグラフにどんな形で反映されるのでしょう？ その説明があると、助言/回答が得られやすくなると思われます。

Comment: 例えば、Y軸の値は`Ygrid = data.index.values.astype(np.float32)`で作っているからで、Index値の`0～98`を表すのでしょう。@metropolis さん提示の対処でY軸は`0～1.0`に、colorbarは`0～0.32`に変わります。希望されているY軸の`0.01～0.05`の値は何処から導き出されるのでしょう？

Comment: お二人ともありがとうございます。`0.01~0.05`ではなく`0.01~1.00`の間違いでした、すみません。

Comment: @metropolis さんの方法で、x軸は2,4,6,8,10,12、y軸は0~1.0にすることができました。
その上で、
①y軸の原点に0を表示させたい、②colorbarは`0~1`で表示させ、実際の等高線図には`0~0.32`しか現れていない、という風にするにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか？

Comment: `@kunif` 現状のものを質問欄に画像で載せました。(色や縮尺は変えたりしています)

Comment: contour.set_clim(vmin=0, vmax=1)の指定も追加しました

Comment: ①のY軸原点0表示は`plt.show()`の前に`ax.set_ylim([0.0,1.0])`を行うことで出来ます。

Comment: ②については levels を指定すると良いかと思います。`contour = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels=np.linspace(0, 1.0, 11))`

Comment: とても読み解くのが大変そうですが、こんな記事を見つけました。[matplotlibのcolorbarを解剖してわかったこと、あるいはもうcolorbar調整に苦労したくない人に捧げる話](https://qiita.com/skotaro/items/01d66a8c9902a766a2c0), [早く知っておきたかったmatplotlibの基礎知識、あるいは見た目の調整が捗るArtistの話](https://qiita.com/skotaro/items/08dc0b8c5704c94eafb9)